# What is the PostgreSQL equivalent of Oracle's DBMS_LOB.substr(TI.STAMP_ITEM_VALUE,200)?

Tags: postgresql, blob

How do I get `DBMS_LOB.substr(TI.STAMP_ITEM_VALUE,200)` to work in PostgreSQL?

Comment: `substr()` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve chunks of large binary values (stream), you would use [large objects](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/lo-interfaces.html) in PostgreSQL.

The equivalent of your call would be

```
loread(openlo, 200)
```